# How to insert a file in a specific target file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I've an osgi server, developed under eclipse, that runs on windows, macosx and linux. 
Tycho and maven are doing the target building configuration for theses platforms perfectly.

Now, I need to insert a startup.sh or startup.bat in the final .zip file according to the final os + ws and arch plateform.
Is there something like a "**configuration.environments.environment.os**" and so on maven variables I could use to copy my **scripts** folder next to the product target folder like this:

```
delivery_folder/
->x86_64/
->scripts/
```

Here's an extract of the product pom file:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/products/${project.artifactId}/${configuration.environments.environment.os}</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>scripts</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I'd like to use Tycho target-environnement mechanism.

I've setup Tycho with:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
<artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
<version>${tycho.version}</version>
 <configuration>
 <environments>
    <environment>
    <os>linux</os>
    <ws>gtk</ws>
    <arch>x86_64</arch>
 </environment>
 <environment>
    <os>win32</os>
    <ws>win32</ws>
    <arch>x86</arch>
 </environment>
 <environment>
    <os>win32</os>
    <ws>win32</ws>
    <arch>x86_64</arch>
 </environment>
 <environment>
    <os>macosx</os>
    <ws>cocoa</ws>
    <arch>x86_64</arch>
    </environment>
 </environments>
</configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the rather *low-level* `maven-resoures-plugin`, you can also use PDE-style rootfiles, which allow platform-specific files to be included in an `eclipse-repository` (which I assume is the packaging type producing your ZIP):

```
root.win32.win32.x86=rootfiles
```

See the [Tycho FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#How_do_I_include_rootfiles.3F) for details. (Note that the upcoming [Tycho version 1.0.0](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/1.0.0) will further improve rootfiles support in Tycho by supporting the `root.folder.<subfolder>` syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use build profiles to accomplish this. You can specify a profile for any platform you support, and optionally add the `activation`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>win32-win32-x86</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <arch>x86</arch>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target.os>win32</target.os>
            <target.ws>win32</target.ws>
            <target.arch>x86</target.arch>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>win32-win32-x86_64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <arch>x86_64</arch>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target.os>win32</target.os>
            <target.ws>win32</target.ws>
            <target.arch>x86_64</target.arch>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>gtk-linux-x86</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <arch>i386</arch>
                <family>unix</family>
                <name>linux</name>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target.os>linux</target.os>
            <target.ws>gtk</target.ws>
            <target.arch>x86</target.arch>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>gtk-linux-amd64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <arch>amd64</arch>
                <family>unix</family>
                <name>linux</name>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target.os>linux</target.os>
            <target.ws>gtk</target.ws>
            <target.arch>x86_64</target.arch>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cocoa-macosx-i386</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <arch>i386</arch>
                <family>unix</family>
                <name>mac os x</name>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target.os>macosx</target.os>
            <target.ws>cocoa</target.ws>
            <target.arch>x86</target.arch>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cocoa-macosx-x86_64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <arch>x86_64</arch>
                <family>unix</family>
                <name>mac os x</name>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target.os>macosx</target.os>
            <target.ws>cocoa</target.ws>
            <target.arch>x86_64</target.arch>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This will set three properties which can be used to configure your directory:

- `${target.os}`
- `${target.ws}`
- `${target.arch}`

Then in your `maven-resources-plugin` configuration:

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/products/${project.artifactId}/${target.os}.${target.ws}.${target.arch}</outputDirectory>
```